# Keydown event auto recall

Tags: events, keydown, devexpress-windows-ui, textedit

i have code:

```
private void textEdit_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{   //line start
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        //Do something
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    } //line done

}
```

when i press enter key, event is fire, after perform something `(cursor == line done)`, i don't know why cursor auto jump to line start and re-perform code in if statement,
pls, let me know if u have solution for this issue (prevent auto re-call)

Comment: Did you try to check who is the sender of the event? Try to use e.Handled property to prevent double firing.

Comment: i don't set `e.Handle = false;` because i want re-press enter key after code in line `//Do Somthing` is wrong (show msg)

Answer (score 0):

A scenario where this can happen, is when the `textEdit_KeyDown` event handler is subscribed more than once, in other words, the `KeyDown` event is handled more than once, by the same handler. I suggest you look in your code and comment (if found), one subscription of the `textEdit_KeyDown` event handler.

```
//textEdit.KeyDown += textEdit_KeyDown;
```

Comment: thanks for your advise, but i'm sure textEdit_KeyDown event handler is only once, and it's recall sometime (no always recall)